# Trying to extract data from tables using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Vista 64 bit. I have the current Scrapy code which is working pretty well now for extracting text, but I'm a bit stuck as to how get data from tables on websites. I've had a look online for answers but I'm still not sure. As an example, I would like to get the data contained in this table for Wayne Rooney's goalscoring stats:

http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney
The code I currently have is this:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "Goals"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for titles in titles:

            body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)

            print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goals'])
```

What syntax do need to use in the xpath() statements to get tabular data?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to get from the page

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the data in what looks like a table below the text 'Wayne Rooney's Match History:'...ive had a look at some of the xpath examples online, but none seem to return anything in this case. I've pressed F12 to examine the page structure, but i'm not really sure what i'm looking at.

Answer (score 3):

I just saw the page link and I got all rows of the table of tournaments you want throughout this Xpath expression: `'//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]'`.

I'll try to explain each part of this Xpath expression:

- `//table[@id="player-fixture"]`: retrieve the whole table with the id attribute `player-fixture` as you can inspect in that page.
- `//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]`: retrive all rows with the information of each match you want.

You can use just this shorter `//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]` Xpath expression as well. But I think is more consistent to use the prior expression as you are stating by that expression that you want all rows(`tr`) under a certain table whose `id` is unique(`player-fixture`).

Once you get all rows, you can loop over them to get all information you need from each row entry.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. using your example above i get all of the information from that table apart from the columns that contain his goals and assists data as they are not represented as text. do you know how i might be able to get them in included in my output as something i can convert into a text like 'goal' and 'assist'?

Comment: @user3045351 hi, I decided to answer you doubt in the next answer instead of a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

To scrape data, you usually identify the table, then loop over the rows.
An html table like this one usually has this format:

```
<table id="thistable">
  <tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's an example of how to parse this fixture table:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from myproject.items import Fixture

class GoalSpider(Spider):
    name = "goal"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.whoscored.com/',
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        return Request(
            url="http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney",
            callback=self.parse_fixtures
        )

    def parse_fixtures(self,response):
        sel = response.selector
        for tr in sel.css("table#player-fixture>tbody>tr"):
             item = Fixture()
             item['tournament'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="tournament"]/span/a/text()').extract()
             item['date'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
             item['team_home'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="team home "]/a/text()').extract()
             yield item
```

First, I identify the data rows with `sel.css("table#player-fixture>tbody>tr")` and loop over the results, then extract data.

Edit: items.py (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)

```
class Fixture(Item):
    tournament = Field()
    date = Field()
    team_home = Field()
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. what is the above module 'myproject.item'? is myproject supposed to represent a name local to me or is there a module specifically called 'myproject' that i need to install?

Comment: myproject is the name of your project. So if you do a `scrapy startproject newproject`, the module will be called newproject. This allows you to access everything in your myproject/myproject folder without using sys.

Comment: my project is called test, so i have tried both 'from test import fixture' and 'from test.items import fixture', neither of which work?

Comment: First you have to declare your items in the file items.py. Then you can import it with `from test.items import Fixture`. I've edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: ok i have amended the contents of items.py. my scrapy project is in the path C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py. the items.py file is one level above that. im still confused as to whether i should be going for 'test.items', 'mrscrap.items' or 'spiders.items'? i have tried all three, but unfortunately none seem to work?

Comment: 'test.items' gives a traceback of 'there is no module called .items' and mrscrap.items gives an error of 'there is no module named mrscrap'.

Comment: You should use "from mrscrap.items import Fixture"

Comment: 'from mrscrap.items import fixture' produces the error message 'there is no module named mrscrap.items'?

Comment: do you have any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with you trying to launch the command line from within the spider. Try to remove the cmd import and the execute call. If nothing works, go back to your top folder and generate a new project with `scrapy startproject myproject`, and a generate a new spider with `scrapy genspider goal whoscored.com -t basic`. Then paste my spider code to spiders/goal.py and my items code to items.py. Then start the spider with `scrapy crawl goal -o output.json`, which will fill the file "output.json".

Answer (score 0):

At first of all, for each symbol that you want you have to know what is the name associate with this symbol. For example, for goals I saw a `<span>` element with title attribute equals *"Goal"* as well as a `<span>` element with title attribute equals *"Assist"* for the symbol assist.

Considering these informations, you could check for each row retrieved if it contains a span with a desired title name that is associate with the symbol that you want to retrieve.

To get all Goals symbols of a row you could eval this row using the expression `//span[@title="Goal"`as bellow:

```
for row in response.selector.xpath(
            '//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tr[td[@class="tournament"]]'):
    # Is this row contains goal symbols?
    list_of_goals = row.xpath('//span[@title="Goal"')
    if list_of_goals:
        # Output goals text.
    .
    .
    .
```

If it has retrieved a no empty list, it means there are goals symbols inside this row. So, you can output how many goals texts as many as the length of the returned list of spans, above.

Comment: where you have put '#output goals text' i have put 'print list_of_goals' and got the following error: ' Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
     self.runUntilCurrent()
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
     call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 383, in callback
     self._startRunCallbacks(result)

Comment: File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 491, in _startRunCallbacks
     self._runCallbacks()
 --- <exception caught here> ---
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
   File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 56, in parse
     raise NotImplementedError
 exceptions.NotImplementedError:'...what have I done wrong?